# Javascript function is not called when the list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, indexeddb

I have a simple app that uses IndexedDb, JQuery and JQuery mobile. I have this showData() function that populates a un-ordered list. All the pages of the app is in one html file.

```
function showData() {
    // clear the item list
    $('#itemList').html('');
    var output = '';
    var objectStore = db.transaction(dbTable).objectStore(dbTable);
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            // generate the list items
            output += '<li>';
            output += '<a href="#details" onclick="displayObject(\'' + cursor.value.SSN + '\')">';
            output += '<h2>' + cursor.value.Name + '</h2>';
            output += '<p>' + cursor.value.Address + '</p>'; 
            output += '</a>';
            output += '<a href="#deleteItem" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Delete Entry</a>';
            output += '</li>';
            // add the list item to UL
            $('#itemList').append(output);
            // clear pervious item
            output = ''; 

            cursor.continue();

        } else {
            //
            $('#notice').append('<p>All Items Loaded Successfully!</p>');
        }
    };
}
```

The list items are show fine and when i click on a list item it should navigate to the details page.. When clicking on the list item a function called diaplayObject(id) function should be called and then it uses the id to get the data and populate the details page. Here is the function

```
function displayObject(id) {
    console.log('In diaplayObject()');
    var objectStore = db.transaction(dbTable).objectStore(dbTable);
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;

        if (cursor) {
            if (cursor.value.SSN == id) {
                $('#name').html(cursor.value.Name);
                $('#address').html(cursor.value.Address);
                return;
            }
            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            $('#name').html('No DATA');
        }
    };
}
```

My problem is this function is not called when i click on the link. I used the debugger in Firefox and the brakepoint will not get hit. i can't figure out what is the problem. What am i doing wrong.

Generated HTML (list items)

```
<ul id="itemList" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="search" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="a" data-theme="a">
            <li class="ui-li-has-alt ui-first-child">
                <a class="ui-btn" href="#details" onclick="displayObject('111')">
                    <h2>Kasun</h2>
                    <p>Imbulgoda</p>
                </a>
                <a title="Delete Entry" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="deleteItem" aria-haspopup="true" href="#deleteItem" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-li-has-alt">
                <a class="ui-btn" href="#details" onclick="displayObject('458')">
                    <h2>Gayan</h2>
                    <p>Gampaha</p>
                </a>
                <a title="Delete Entry" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="deleteItem" aria-haspopup="true" href="#deleteItem" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-li-has-alt">
                <a class="ui-btn" href="#details" onclick="displayObject('881')">
                <h2>Kasun</h2>
                <p>Gampaha</p>
            </a>
            <a title="Delete Entry" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete ui-btn-a" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="deleteItem" aria-haspopup="true" href="#deleteItem" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Is there a console error? It's worth examining and possibly posting the actual generated HTML. For example, I'm not sure your quotes match up properly.

Comment: Is `displayObject` global? That is, declared at the top level of a `script` element, **outside** anything else? (E.g., not in any function, like a `ready` callback.)

Comment: displayObject function is inside the function associated with window.onload. I'll edit the question with generated HTML.

Comment: See @JacobMattison's comment above: There was a console error telling you why it wasn't working.

Comment: forgot to put it down. There were no console errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> displayObject function is inside the function associated with window.onload.

That's the problem. Functions called from `onXyz` attributes **must** be global. That's one of the several reasons not to use `onXyz` attributes.

Here's a mock-up of your code with `displayObject` as a global — it works: http://jsbin.com/nakak/1

Here's a mock-up with `displayObject` wrapped in a `window.onload` handler — it fails with `Uncaught ReferenceError: displayObject is not defined`: http://jsbin.com/nakak/2

I'd use a `data-*` attribute and a delegated handler instead, with the handler getting the `id` from the element. That looks like this: http://jsbin.com/nakak/3

Putting the `data-*` attribute on:

```
output += '<a href="#details" data-id="' + cursor.value.SSN + '">';
```

Binding the handler to `#itemList`:

```
$("#itemList").on("click", "a[data-id]", displayObject);
```

Then in `displayObject`, get the `id`:

```
function displayObject() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    // ...
}
```

Or if you use `displayObject` elsewhere and so don't want to change it, you'd bind the handler like this instead:

```
$("#itemList").on("click", "a[data-id]", function() {
    displayObject($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Comment: You are right :) got it working by moving the function to a global scope.. But i will use the implementation you suggested. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the function call from the HTML attribute and instead add an event listener for a class or ID? Something like this:

```
output+= '<a href="#details" class="displayObjectLink" id="' + cursor.value.SSN + '">';

//event listener which will call the function

var URLclick = document.querySelectorAll('displayObjectLink');

URLclick.addEventLisenter('click', displayObject);
```

and then in tour displayObject, you can access the cursor.value.SSN by retrieving the ID of the element:

```
var SSN = event.target.id; //you must pass in the event as the first argument of the function
```